# How can I get messageId after sending to RabbitMq?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I want some messageId kind of thing when I am sending to Rabbit Mq Queue as I will get when sending to IBM MQ using jms. I am using spring MQ amqp starter dependency with Spring Boot. Configuration is done only in application.yml (property file). I am using Rabbit template for sending.

```
rabbitMqTemplate.convertAndSend(EMPTY_STRING,queueName, message, messagePostProcessor);
```

I have tried messagePostProcessor. Any help is appreciated. I had a look into below content. But didnt understand how to implement. Does it require special configuration (connectionfactory/ container)?

https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike JMS, the rabbit client doesn't assign message ids.

However, you can configure the `RabbitTemplate`'s `MessageConverter` to create an id, which you can then retrieve with a post processor.

See `AbstractMessageConverter`...

```
/**
 * Flag to indicate that new messages should have unique identifiers added to their properties before sending.
 * Default false.
 * @param createMessageIds the flag value to set
 */
public void setCreateMessageIds(boolean createMessageIds) {
    this.createMessageIds = createMessageIds;
}
```

For message confirmations, see the [reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#template-confirms). But that is unrelated to the message id property.

Comment: can you please look into this and help us??
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967932/is-there-any-configuration-to-connect-to-queue-with-same-name-on-different-broke

Comment: I'm using Jackson2JsonMessageConverter. I use setCreateMessageIds with value true, but If get messageId from my message it's null. Any ideas? Same if I use messageKeyGenerator in StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor. The only way I can use messageId is if I put it in MessagePostProcessor. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on 4 year old answers. Ask a new question showing your code and configuration.