# Is there any configuration to connect to queue with same name on different broker on failure?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I just want to know if there is configuration property in spring-amqp to auto connect to the hosts given in application property file which has same queue name!

For example, I have around 20 queues that will be used to publish and consume by around 10 small spring boot applications in a VM(server1) and if some things happens to queues/rabbitmq node on server1, then it should connect to same set of queues on server2 (whose host/addresses could be given `application.property` file - clustered/ non clustered nodes - all methods are fine for me). This could have been solved by [Mirroring](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) queue, but they involve performance degradation(transferring to other node and extra network trip by apps on other server whose nodes on which queues doesn't reside)

Not a great programmer now! Please ignore my ignorance! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are suggesting makes no sense, unless you are willing to lose messages and the queues are configured for auto-deletion.

If that's the case, it will "just work", simply use `host1,host2` and, as long as the queues/bindings etc are configured as Spring `@Bean`s, when the connection fails over, the queues will be declared on the new broker.

It doesn't make any sense for non-auto-delete queues since it is possible that messages still exist on the failed broker (and they will be consumed the next time we connect, but now there could be stale messages on the second broker).

Comment: thanks for your reply. So you are suggesting for mirroring. Can you please suggest what are the things/how we should do it?

Comment: How do you think i should design my rabbit connections/ queues/ nodes ? Mirrored queues and clustered nodes and apps publishing and consuming from respective queues enough??

Comment: It's usually sufficient. In extreme environments, you can consider using a `LocalizedQueueConnectionFactory` so we consume from the node that masters the queue but it most environments, that's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks Gary, Do I really need publisher confirms and returns? our team was suggesting of not wasting resources for them and sending to queue is done in a try catch.

Comment: You should really ask a new question, since it's unrelated. Sending in a try/catch won't guarantee anything; sends are asynchronous.